# Play (Scala), Reactivemongo and multiple databases

Tags: scala, playframework, reactivemongo

So, been working on a smaller project with Play, ReactiveMongo and MongoDB. My question is about the `application.conf` part for ReactiveMongo, have the standard googlable one:

```
mongodb = {
  db = "db1"
  servers = [ "localhost:27017" ]
  credentials = {
    username = "auser"
    password = "apassword"
  }
}
```

And to access a collection, in Scala:

```
def sessionCollection: JSONCollection = db.collection[JSONCollection]("session")
```

So, since MongoDB locks at database level for writes, I'm looking for a solution to use several databases.

Question is: how do I configure multiple databases so I can define collections like above, from those databases?

MongoDB 2.6.x, Play 2.3.x, Reactivemongo 0.10.5.0.akka23

Edit: I should say that I  already know about [this](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.10/documentation/tutorial/connect-database.html), doing it manually with code, but I wanted to know if there were any Play specific known solution I've failed to reach via Google.

Comment: As indicated in the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/tutorial/play.html), since 0.12.0 "you can use ReactiveMongo with multiple connection pools (possibly with different replica sets and/or different options), using the @NamedDatabase annotation"

Comment: Thank you for that input, @cchantep. Can you please write that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Play application, you can use ReactiveMongo with multiple connection pools (possibly with different replica sets and/or different options), using the `@NamedDatabase` annotation.

Consider the following configuration, with several connection URIs.

```
# The default URI
mongodb.uri = "mongodb://someuser:somepasswd@localhost:27017/foo"

# Another one, named with 'bar'
mongodb.bar.uri = "mongodb://someuser:somepasswd@localhost:27017/lorem"
```

Then the dependency injection can select the API instances using the names.

import javax.inject.Inject

```
import play.modules.reactivemongo._

class MyComponent @Inject() (
  val defaultApi: ReactiveMongoApi, // corresponds to 'mongodb.uri'
  @NamedDatabase("bar") val barApi: ReactiveMongoApi // 'mongodb.bar'
) {

}
```